# Need help naming / finding drill attachment

Tags: tools

I have a ZUWA drill pump as seen in the picture but not the attachment to the drill that stabilizes the water pump (the thing that has the metal rod extending out that passes through the water pump) 
 It's not absolutely necessary, but a nice-to-have.  I've had some trouble locating one and not sure how common they are, or if they have a common name?

On ZUWA's website I could only find an ID for this part.

Any help much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Hey that's a cool gadget! I've never seen one of those before!

Comment: `I could probably find one on the company's website` ... then do so .... that's how you figure out the name and the seller

Comment: @Matthew Yep!  Lots of potential uses for this, it's one of my favorite attachments (minus the attachment I'm looking to complete it with)

Comment: @jsotola hey bud!  all I could find was an ID, hence the reason I'm posting.

Comment: you made it sound like you did not check the company's website

Comment: Many drills provide a depth bar - this just appears to be an extra bracket...

Comment: I use that exact drill every day. It came with a depth bar, and that's not it.

Comment: The handle for the stop on a 18v Dewalt hammer drill [looks like this](https://www.oilybits.com/flexible-impeller-pumps-shaft-driven-with-drill-adaptor-stainless-steel.html) (about halfway down the page)  - looks like you need the piece on top of the pump, and an offset rod (or just have the handle angled funny).

Comment: [Part 300, Drill adapter 11012300](https://www.zuwa.de/fileadmin/user_upload/Downloads/EN/parts_lists/partlist_unistar_2001B.pdf) is an OEM part. If you don't have that you're probably SoL. Contact them (with your phone, scary I know...) and ask them which of their distributors carry it.

Comment: I have to use a phone?   Thanks for your comments.  I know a little more now than when I started this thread thanks to you guys.  If I find any extra info will post an answer. @Mazura @ Solar Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just the depth gauge that is built into the front handle of most two-hand drills.

[image]
Green is an accessory typically supplied with the drill.

Red is an accessory for the pump, Part 300, Drill adapter 11012300
it doesn't appear tp be particularly complex design you could screw a bracket to a block of wood and put a metal rod through the wood and have something near equivalent